# How to achieve a united resolution for all 3D meshes?

Tags: 3d, resolution, mesh

I have various 3D meshes in my DB, and every one has a different resolution from others. So I am seeking for some methods in the state of the art to render all object with the same resolution.

I know, but I am not sure, that may be we can use loop subdivision on each mesh but I wonder, if it is possible, how to achieve a united resolution for all meshes! And if there are some other methods I would like to know it so that I could read about them.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by resolution of 3D mesh? it is Voxel map or just rendered 2D image/slice ?

Comment: Mesh resolution is defined as the median of all edge lengths in a mesh.

Comment: Then just compute the resolution `l` and rescale all vertexes to achieve some defined resolution (like `l0=1`) so `vertex[i]*=l0/l` That should be `~O(m.n.log(n))` where `m` is number of meshes and `n` is average edge count per mesh. So where is the problem ? What do you mean by state of the art. To compute median you need to sort the edges lengths which is the slowest operation so I see no improvements possible unless you want just estimated medians (computed from some edges not all)